# script tag in java script is not working and dynamic addition too

Tags: html, script-tag, dynamic-html

I'm trying to add a `script` tag as value of a variable within a `script`.
that is ..

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var iCnt = 0;
        $('#btAdd').click(function() {
            if (iCnt <= 19) {
                iCnt = iCnt + 1;
                var div = '<div id="node' + iCnt + '" class="item">'+ iCnt +'</div>';
                var jsplmb = '<script> jsPlumb.ready(function() { addPlumb("node'+ iCnt +'") });</script>';
                $('#diagramContainer').after(div);
            }
        });
 });

</script>
```

which is not working. The `close script tag` in the variable `jsplumb` act as the `close tag` of main `script tag`.

also the dynamic addition of `var div` is not adding to

```
<div id="diagramContainer"> </div>
```

Comment: also the dynamic addition of html components is not working. pls give a solution for that too..

Comment: BTW, your `jsplmb` does nothing and is never used.

Comment: what about `div` ..  its not working (the html elements are not adding )

Comment: Seems to be working: http://jsbin.com/ruzumu/2/watch?html,js,output Unless you have the wrong selector `#diagramContainer`

Comment: its showing an warning message : `Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead`. Is the problem . Any way its not working even after coping your entire code. But its work in `JS Bin`

Comment: Sounds like you have more code than this snippet. I suggest you ask a new questions minus the `jsplmb` stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script tags are parsed before the code inside them, so the browser doesn't know that you intended the closing script tag to be a string in the code.

You can break up the closing script tag into separate strings:

```
var jsplmb = '<script> jsPlumb.ready(function() { addPlumb("node'+ iCnt +'") });</scr' + 'ipt>';
```